# Athletics Ranking Database - Number of Tables

Tags: database

I'm fairly new to this so you may have to bear with me. I'm developing a database for a website with athletics rankings on them and I was curious as to how many tables would be the most efficient way of achieving this.

I currently have 2 tables, a table called 'athletes' which holds the details of all my runners (potentially around 600 people/records) which contains the following fields:

mid (member id - primary key)
firstname
lastname
gender
birthday
nationality

And a second table, 'results', which holds all of their performances and has the following fields:

mid
eid (event id - primary key)
eventdate
eventcategory (road, track, field etc)
eventdescription (100m, 200m, 400m etc)
hours
minutes
seconds
distance
points
location

The second table has around 2000 records in it already and potentially this will quadruple over time, mainly because there are around 30 track events, 10 field, 10 road, cross country, relays, multi-events etc and if there are 600 athletes in my first table, that equates to a large amount of records in my second table.

So what I was wondering is would it be cleaner/more efficient to have multiple tables to separate track, field, cross country etc?

I want to use the database to order peoples results based on their performance. If you would like to understand better what I am trying to emulate, take a look at this website http://thepowerof10.info

Answer (score 1):

Changing the schema won't change the number of results.  Even if you split the venue into a separate table, you'll still have one result per participant at each event.

The potential benefit of having a separate venue table would be better normalization.  A runner can have many results, and a given venue can have many results on a given date.  You won't have to repeat the venue information in every result record.

You'll want to pay attention to indexes.  Every table must have a primary key.  Add additional indexes for columns you use in WHERE clauses when you select.

Here's a [discussion about normalization](http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/normalization.htm) and what it can mean for you.

PS - Thousands of records won't be an issue.  Large databases are on the order of giga- or tera-bytes.

Comment: So if you were to have a separate table for venue I presume you would only have one one table with all the venues in with something along the lines of:
<br/>
vid (venue id - primary key)<br>
venuename<br>
<br>
Would there be much else you would have in the table? Or would you have a separate table for each venue? The number of venues is probably potentially in the 300 range so I presume not?

Answer (score 0):

My thought --

Don't break your events table into separate tables for each type (track, field, etc.).  You'll have a much easier time querying the data back out if it's all there in the same table.

Otherwise, your two tables look fine -- it's a good start.